# porque me toma un dato mi FOR - python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Hice el recorrido de mis arreglos/listas, pero al momento de hacer pruebas, los dos primeros **FOR** me funcionan bien, pero el tercero, me causa problemas ¿Por qué?, Bueno, el tercero debería ir dentro del segundo **FOR**, pero al momento de meterlos los  datos que me da mi segundo FOR que son 7 registros los que me bota, al meterlo solo me arroja el primero, y a mi me interesa que en el tercer FOR me recorra cada uno de los 7 registros.

```
for a in range(0,len(timePlanned)):
    temp = timePlanned[a]['PlannedStartDateTime']
    PlanStart.append(temp)
for tPl in range(0,len(PlanStart)):
    fecha = PlanStart[tPl].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    fechaInicio = PlanStart[tPl].strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    FeIn.append(fechaInicio)
    print FeIn
```

Me da como resultado esto:

[image: Me da como resultado esto:]

y el tercer **FOR** que va dentro den segundo es:

```
  for fif , fef in zip(DateFIF, DateFEF): 
        if FeIn[tPl]== None:
            print("no hay registro")
        else:
            if fif <= FeIn[tPl]<= fef:
                timeProcessIn = sWarehouseMovementProcessIn.objects.filter(Q(DateTimeMovement__lte=fecha)).values('UnitQuantity','JobPlannedID')
                x = timeProcessIn.values('JobPlannedID')
                timePlanned = sJobPlanned.objects.filter(Q(PlannedEndDateTime__gte=fecha)).values('id','PlannedQuantity')
                timeJob2 = sJob.objects.filter(Q(RealStartDateTime__gte=fecha)).values('id','RealQuantity'),'RealQuantity','RealStartDateTime','RealEndDateTime'
```

Solo me recorre el primer valor de la primera posición.

[image: Como se muestra]

cuando debería de salirme así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese caso el primer dato que me arroja es de mi arreglo tanto como el ultimo, y el que esta en medio, es el dato que se va a comparar con los arreglos que tiene a la orilla, el cual, eso debería de hacerme con los 7 datos y solo me lo hace con el primero.

¿Por qué?